# Calling clean_term_cache() fails when called in the same plugin that creates terms, succeeds when called separately?

Tags: plugin-development, categories

My plugin code is below. In the myPlugin_cleanup() function, I'm creating some categories and assigning term id 1 as the parent.

Due to the [**known bug with creating categories via script**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15066/missing-category-children-option-when-dynamically-creating-categories-via-a-plu) (the category_children array does not get created and results in a fatal error when pages containing category listings are accessed), I've placed the clean_term_cache() call directly below the function that creates my categories.

However, its not working. The category_children option is not getting created.

Interestingly, if I create a plugin whose sole function is to execute the clean_term_cache('','category') call, it fixes the problem and creates the category_children option with the correct values.

I'm just not sure why its not working in the same plugin that creates the categories.

What might I be missing?

```
function myPlugin_activate(){
    if ( get_option( 'myPlugin_activated' ) !== "1"){
        //comment out any function you don't want to run
        myPlugin_copy('themes');
        myPlugin_copy('plugins');
        myPlugin_images();
        myPlugin_options();
        myPlugin_settings();
        myPlugin_widgets();
        myPlugin_links();
        myPlugin_posts();
        myPlugin_pages();
        myPlugin_custom_menus();
        myPlugin_cleanup();
        clean_term_cache('','category'); //does not work here
        update_option('myPlugin_activated', "1");
        }
    }

function myPlugin_cleanup(){

        //include dependencies
        require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php');    

        if(!get_cat_ID('nofollow')){wp_create_category('nofollow',1);}
        if(!get_cat_ID('noindex')){wp_create_category('noindex',1);}

        clean_term_cache('','category'); //Does not appear to work here either.
        }


register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'myPlugin_activate');
?>
```

Comment: Update: It appears that the fix for this is to call    _get_term_hierarchy('category') NOT clean_term_cache('','category');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating about 40 test WP installs today on localhost, here's what I can report:

It appears that the correct function call to rebuild the category_children options is:

```
_get_term_hierarchy('category')
```

Previously, I was trying to call:

```
clean_term_cache('','category')
```

And I was calling it just after my categories were created in my plugin code. However, I could never get this function to do anything when called from the same plugin that I'm using to create the categories. Interestingly, I could place the function in a stand-alone plugin and run it (after my category creation plugin) and it would rebuild the category_parents options array perfectly.

The reason it can't be called in the same script that creates the categories appears to be related to a peculiar behavior of clean_term_cache() which is best stated by "foofy" in a comment in [**the bug track ticket**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14704):

> This is only a problem if you make
>   multiple term changes in the same PHP
>   request/script lifetime.
>   clean_term_cache() tracks each
>   taxonomy it cleans in a static
>   variable and won't clean it a second
>   time. If several term changes are made
>   in the same request, the
>   {$taxonomy}_children option is left
>   with the hierarchy as it was after the
>   first change.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this:

```
$taxnomy_name = ...;
clean_term_cache ( _get_term_hierarchy($taxnomy_name), $taxnomy_name);
```

Comment: Can you explain that?